# MapThread with non-rectangular lists

Tags: list-manipulation

`MapThread` works fine and dandy with rectangular list structures:

```
MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, 2]
```

> `{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4]}}`

But with a ragged structure, it starts complaining:

```
MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}}, 2]
```

> MapThread::mptd: "Object {{a,b},{c,d,e}} at position {2, 1} in MapThread[f,{{{a,b},{c,d,e}},{{1,2},{3,4,5}}},2] has only 1 of required 2 dimensions."

whereas I'd like:

> `{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}`

I can't see any obvious way to achieve a pairing of the corresponding elements, but maybe you can?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, as a more general alternative? However, without tweaking it forget about level specification

```
Function[Null, f[##], Listable] @@ A
```

Comment: The magic of `Listable`!  I knew there must have been some nice way to do it.

Comment: @wxffles I like it. If you actually want to give the arguments as separate lists like in your solution, you don't even need the `Apply`

Comment: This is crazy amazing! MMA is effin' nuts in its state space a.e.!

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to do it by mapping `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[f, #] & /@ Transpose[{{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}}]
(* {{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}} *)
```

Comment: This works great if you are working at level 2.  I was hoping for something more general.  Next time I'll try asking!

Comment: @wxffles please provide more examples if you want a more general solution.

Answer (score 12):

It's probably bad form to answer your own question, but I did manage to get something to work while I was waiting:

```
myMapThread[f_, list1_, list2_, level_] := 
  Module[{s}, Function[s, 
     Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[f[#1, s[[Sequence @@ #2]]]] &, list1, {level}]][[1]]]
     [list2]];
```

Usage:

```
myMapThread[f, {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, 2]
```

> `{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}`

It's quite ugly though.

Comment: It's not bad form, in fact it is [actively encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).

Answer (score 7):

```
ClearAll[raggedThread]
raggedThread = Inner[Thread @* #, ##2, List] &;
```

**Example:**

```
raggedThread[f, {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}
> ```

Comment: Necromancer badge :-)

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 6):

```
MapThread[f, lst[[1 ;; 2, #]]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

gives

```
(*{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}*)
```

If

```
lst2 = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{aa, bb}, {cc, dd, ee}}};
MapThread[f, lst2[[1 ;; 3, #]]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

gives

```
(*{{f[a, 1, aa], f[b, 2, bb]}, {f[c, 3, cc], f[d, 4, dd], f[e, 5, ee]}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {{a, b}, {c, d, e}};
y = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};

MapApply[f] /@ Transpose /@ Transpose[{x, y}]
```

{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}

Answer (score 1):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy` to cover the ragged array case:

```
myMapThread[f_, list_] := 
If[TensorQ[list], f @@@ # &@*Thread /@ Transpose@list, 
Values[GroupBy[Catenate[list], Length, f @@@ # &@*Thread]]]
```

Testing `myMapThread`:

```
list1 = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
list2 = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}};

myMapThread[f, list1]

(*{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4]}}*)

myMapThread[f, list2]

(*{{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]}, {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
threadRagged = Apply[#, Flatten[{##2}, {{2}, {3}}], {2}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
{x, y} = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, y = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}};

threadRagged[f, x, y]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]},   
>  {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}
> ```

```
lst2 = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{aa, bb}, {cc, dd, ee}}};

threadRagged[F, ## & @@ lst2]
```

> ```
>  {{F[a, 1, aa], F[b, 2, bb]},   
>   {F[c, 3, cc], F[d, 4, dd], F[e, 5, ee]}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
threadTwice = Map[Thread]@Thread[#@##2, List, Length @ {##2}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
{x, y} = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, y = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}};

threadTwice[f, x, y]
```

> ```
>  {{f[a, 1], f[b, 2]},   
>   {f[c, 3], f[d, 4], f[e, 5]}}
> ```

```
lst2 = {{{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{aa, bb}, {cc, dd, ee}}};

threadTwice[f, ## & @@ lst2]
```

> ```
> {{f[a, 1, aa], f[b, 2, bb]},   
>  {f[c, 3, cc], f[d, 4, dd], f[e, 5, ee]}}
> ```