# MapThread over sublists of different length

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which looks like this: `l={{1,0,3,4},{0,2},{0,0,1,3},{1,2,0}}`. Now I would like to count how many 0s the sublists contain in the first, second,... slot.
The result for this example should be: `{2,2,1,0}`. Since the sublists do not have the same length `MapThread` does not work.

I would be grateful for a solution.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3643)

Comment: Also related: [(6102)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6102/121)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `Flatten` to transpose a ragged array:

```
list = {{1, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0}}

Count[#, 0] & /@ Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]
(* {2, 2, 1, 0} *)
```

**Edit**

Step one is to transpose your list but in this case the list is ragged so `Tranpose` doesn't work:

```
Transpose[list]
```

However `Flatten` can transpose a ragged list (type `Flatten` in the documentation center and then go to "Applications"):

```
Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 2}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 3}} *)
```

Now that the list is transposed you can count the number of zeros, this is done by mapping the transposed list onto `Count`

```
Map[Count[#, 0] &, Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]]
```

Comment: it is one of those cool tricks "hidden" in the documentation, i.e. I doubt you'd find it by searching "transpose ragged array."

Comment: that's a great solution and it works perfectly. Unfortunately I, by now, dont understand completly how it actually works

Comment: @rainer I just added an edit that hopefully explains how this works.

Comment: thank you! this does explain a lot

Comment: is it possible to transform this one in order to calculate the mean instead of counting zeros?

Comment: +1. The `{1}` is optional btw

Answer (score 16):

I propose this:

```
Total @ PadRight[1 - Unitize[list]]
```

Comment: +1 great one... Don't pay attention to the ellipsis. The comment just needed 3 extra characters to not be too short... (I was referring to the first ellipsis, not this last one)

Comment: Not general, but slick. +1

Comment: @Rojo, how appropriate that you had to `PadRight` your comment :-)

Answer (score 11):

Say you have

```
l = {{1, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}};
```

There is a bit different approach to your function:

```
Sort@Tally@Position[l, 0][[All, 2]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}}

which is compressed from of your information. It gives you slot index and number of 0s there. If slot has no zeros it is not mentioned. If you have a lot of zero-less slots such format is much shorter.

```
Grid[{{"slot", "zeros"}}~Join~%, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

And here is clunky exercise in padding arrays (with help of Mike's comment) :

```
zcount[l_List] := With[{m = Max[Length /@ l]}, (Count[#, 0] & /@ 
                         Transpose[PadRight[#, m, None] & /@ l])]
```

The usage:

```
zcount[l]
```

> {2, 2, 1, 0, 1}

Comment: I'd do `Count[#, 0] &` instead of `Length /@ (Cases[#, 0] &` but there are probably timing differences depending on how big his real list is.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch forgot about `Count[#, 0]` ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Since `MapThread` accepts a level specification, I think our ragged MapThread function should too.

```
raggedMapThread[f_, expr_, level_Integer: 1] :=
  Apply[f, Flatten[expr, List /@ Range[2, level + 1]], {level}]
```

To solve the specific case posed in the question:

```
raggedMapThread[
  Count[{##}, 0] &,
  {{1, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0}}
]
```

> {2, 2, 1, 0}

Extended to level 2 with an example function `test`:

```
a = {{{67, 47}, {5, 99}, {70, 44}, {9}},
     {{75, 70}, {61}, {16, 23}, {50, 80}},
     {{87, 11}, {10}, {29, 16}}};

PadRight[a, Automatic, ""] // MatrixForm  (* for illustration *)

raggedMapThread[test, a, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: how would you parallelize raggedMapThread?

Comment: @s0rce since there is no "ParallelApply" (at least not in v7) you would need to use something like `ParallelMap`:  `raggedMapThread[f_, expr_, level_Integer: 1] := 
 ParallelMap[Function[, f @@ #, HoldAll], 
  Flatten[expr, List /@ Range[2, level + 1]], {level}]`  the `HoldAll` function might be replaced with `f @@ # &` if you are certain of no surprise evaluations.

Answer (score 5):

Since

> [image]

and

> [image]

the following variations also work:

```
list = {{1, 0, 3, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}};
Count[#, 0] & /@ Transpose@PadRight[list, Automatic, "x"]
(* or *)
Tr /@ Transpose@PadRight[Map[Boole[# == 0] &, list, {-1}]]
(* or *)
Plus @@ PadRight[Boole[# == 0] & /@ # & /@ list]
(* => {2,2,1,0,1} *)
```

EDIT: Few more ways:

```
Rest@Total@BinCounts@Position[list, 0]
Count[Position[list, 0], {_, #}] & /@ Range@Length@list
Length@Position[Position[list, 0], {_, #}] & /@ Range@Length@list
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for when you have one list and one scalar.  Perhaps it can be adapted to your needs -- maybe I'll come back and edit it tailored to your use-case a little more later, but I think you'll get the point.

EDIT: Just saw that this post was from 2012; maybe I won't rush on tailoring it to your needs, but this post came up near the top in my Google search, so maybe somebody else will get some use out of these...

**Method 1**

```
Inner[MyFunction, {d}, {{a, b, c}}]
Inner[MyFunction, {{a, b, c}}\[Transpose], {d}, Reverse]
```

Output (they're equivalent) [leaving it to the reader to do it in the opposite order]:

```
{MyFunction[d, a], MyFunction[d, b], MyFunction[d, c]}
```

**Method 2** - might be more adaptable for you:

```
Outer[MyFunction, {a, b, c}, {d}]
```

Output:

```
{{MyFunction[a, d]}, {MyFunction[b, d]}, {MyFunction[c, d]}}
```

**Method 3**

```
Distribute[MyFunction[{a, b, c}, d], List]
```

Output:

```
{{MyFunction[a, d]}, {MyFunction[b, d]}, {MyFunction[c, d]}}
```

**Update -- GENERAL-CASE SOLUTIONS:**

- These were also written to work with any combination of lists and scalars...

```
DistributeOp[distributeOver_] := Function[expr, Distribute[expr, distributeOver]]
EnsureList[expr_] := Flatten[{expr}, 1]

MapThreadRagged1[func_, a_, b_] := Inner[func, {EnsureList[a]}\[Transpose], {EnsureList[b]}]
MapThreadRagged2[func_, a_, b_] := Outer[func, EnsureList[a], EnsureList[b]]
MapThreadRagged3[func_, a_, b_] := DistributeOp[List]@func[EnsureList[a], EnsureList[b]]
```

Output:

```
MapThreadRagged1[f, {a, b}, {c, d}]
MapThreadRagged1[f, a, b]
MapThreadRagged2[f, {a, b}, {c, d}]
MapThreadRagged2[f, a, b]
MapThreadRagged3[f, {a, b}, {c, d}]
MapThreadRagged3[f, a, b]

{{f[a, c], f[a, d]}, {f[b, c], f[b, d]}}
{{f[a, b]}}

{{f[a, c], f[a, d]}, {f[b, c], f[b, d]}}
{{f[a, b]}}

{f[a, c], f[a, d], f[b, c], f[b, d]}
{f[a, b]}
```