# How to add lists with unequal length?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given lists of unequal lengths, I want to add them together element-wise, treating missing elements as zero. For example, `{1, 2, 3} + {a, b} + {x}` should give `{1 + a + x, 2 + b, 3}`.

How do I write a function to do this?

Comment: for two lists, `fadd[a_, b_] := (PadRight[a, Length@b] + b) /; Length[b] > Length[a];
fadd[a_, b_] := (PadRight[b, Length@a] + a) /; Length[a] > Length[b]` should work. This can be modified for more than two lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Plus @@ PadRight[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x}}]
```

I think it can also work.

Comment: Neat and simple,I can define fadd=Plus @@ PadRight[{##}]&;

Answer (score 17):

You can simply do a [ragged transpose](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3644/5) and then add, which saves you the trouble of having to pad the lists:

```
Total /@ Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x}}, {2}]
(* {1 + a + x, 2 + b, 3} *)
```

Comment: I notice you've exceeded 100 silver badges. Wow! :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've had it for a while now :) Now I need to catch the slow train to a [tag:list-manipulation] gold to join you (you're just mere days away).

Comment: This works, too: `Total[Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x}}, {2}], {2}]`

Answer (score 3):

Using `raggedMapThread` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9028/121) we could write:

```
raggedMapThread[Plus, {{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x}}]
```

> ```
> {1 + a + x, 2 + b, 3}
> ```

This is can also be easily extended to additional dimensions:

```
raggedMapThread[Plus, {{{1}, {2, 3}}, {{a, b}, {q}}, {{x}}}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1 + a + x, b}, {2 + q, 3}}
> ```

Again for reference the code is:

```
raggedMapThread[f_, expr_, level_Integer: 1] := 
 Apply[f, Flatten[expr, List /@ Range[2, level + 1]], {level}]
```