# How can I thread lists of different sizes?

Tags: list-manipulation

What I need is the equivalent of Maple's zip(`+`, A, B, 0).
Sure I can get it with:

```
Thread[PadRight[A, max = Max[Length[A], Length[B]]] + PadRight[B, max]]
```

But is there a less verbose way to do this?

P.S. Eventually the shortest solution seems to be:

```
 Plus @@ PadRight[{A, B}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22437/121

Comment: In your code `Thread` is useless (because `Plus` is Listable) and `PadRight[A, max = Max[Length[A], Length[B]]] + PadRight[B, max]` can be rewritten as `Plus @@ PadRight[{A,B}]`

Comment: 'Plus' was used as an example

Answer (score 8):

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {q, r, s, t, u};
Plus @@@ Flatten[{a, b}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {1 + q, 2 + r, 3 + s, t, u}
> ```

See: [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/121)

For convenience:

```
SetAttributes[myThread, HoldFirst]
myThread[h_[args__]] := h @@@ Flatten[{args}, {2}]
```

Now:

```
myThread[a + b]
```

> ```
> {1 + q, 2 + r, 3 + s, t, u}
> ```

[This utility](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9028/121) may also be useful.

---

The reason I showed use of `Flatten` rather than `PadRight` is that it is more general.  With `PadRight` your function will see zeros:

```
Times @@ PadRight[{a, b}]
```

> ```
> {q, 2 r, 3 s, 0, 0}
> ```

Compare to:

```
myThread[a*b]
```

> ```
> {q, 2 r, 3 s, t, u}
> ```

Of course for `Times` you could pad with ones, but the point is that the padding element would have to be changed to match the function, and for some functions no padding element would be correct.

Comment: Transposing ragged arrays with `Flatten[array,{2}]` is one of my favorite tricks.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility, which I cannot judge as equivalent to Maple's zip, is to use Distribute:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {q, r, s, t, u};

Distribute[f[a, b], List]
```

> {f(1,q),f(1,r),f(1,s),f(1,t),f(1,u),f(2,q),f(2,r),f(2,s),f(2,t),f(2,u),f(3,q),f(3,r),f(3,s),f(3,t),f(3,u)}

If f is List, the result is:

```
Distribute[{a, b}, List]
```

> {{1, q}, {1, r}, {1, s}, {1, t}, {1, u}, {2, q}, {2, r}, {2, s}, {2, t}, 
>    {2, u}, {3, q}, {3, r}, {3, s}, {3, t}, {3, u}}

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. The result should be `{1 + q, 2 + r, 3 + s, t, u}`

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes you are right: now I understood better the question. Thanks

Comment: Delete then perhaps?