# What is the relationship between Thread and MapThread

Tags: functions, core-language

I hope this is not a silly question, since there are plenty of questions on `Thread` and `MapThread`. However, I still cannot quite understand the relationship between them. It seems `MapThread` can take a level argument, but `Thread` cannot. `Thread` can do something like `Thread[f[{a, b, c}, x]]`, `MapThread` cannot. Why we have two of them?

Following two commands give the same results:

```
MapThread[f, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
Thread[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: "MapThread works like Thread, but takes the function and arguments separately..." - straight from the documentation.  They can be used to get the same results, and each has some giblets the other lacks (e.g., specifying the head to thread over in `Thread`). Read, understand and experiment with the examples in the documentation, everything you ever wanted to know is there.

Comment: @ciao does it means actually these two function are almost the same? It is a redundant design for convince.

Comment: `Thread` has been here since V1. `MapThread` was added in V2, since the need to map something over sets of equal length lists is common (effectively mapping the threading over sets made up from the Nth elements of each list), made sense to add it. In addition, there are differences in evaluation - `MapThread` evaluates on each set as you progress, `Thread` attempts to evaluate *the whole expression* before attempting to thread it. Room (and need) for both...

Comment: @ciao An example of this is `Thread[Plus[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]]` vs `MapThread[Plus, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst, Shouldn't the example be "`Thread[Plus[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]]` vs `MapThread[Plus, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]`", which doesn't quite show what you wanted to. Perhaps `Thread[Equal[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 6}]]` vs `MapThread[Equal, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 6}}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, thank you for finding this mistake!

Comment: Obvious, but see also the sections [Properties and relations](http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1kc43u6-gxini4) and [Possible issues](http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1kc43u6-2xrtzt) sections of `MapThread`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With one addition the difference is as you describe in your own question:

- `MapThread` takes the head separately
- `MapThread` only operates upon `List` expressions
- `MapThread` does not distribute singletons
- `MapThread` accepts a level specification

The first characteristic simplifies threading functions that are eager to evaluate:

```
f = Print;
one = {a, b, c};
two = {x, y, z};

MapThread[f, {one, two}];

Thread[f[one, two]];
```

> ax
>
> by
>
> cz
>
> {a,b,c}{x,y,z}

In the second form `Print` evaluates to [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null.html) giving `Thread` nothing to do.  To make `Thread` work one would need to keep `Print` unevaluated while allowing `one` and `two` to resolve:

```
Block[{Print},
  Thread[f[one, two]]
];
```

That `MapThread` does not distribute singletons is something I have no explanation for. I have wished that it *would* work that way but I may have failed to comprehend the ramifications of that behavior.  Perhaps it was determined that the interaction with level specification would be too confusing or arbitrary.

#### Exploration

Here is an attempt at implementing a `MapThread` variant with both level and head parameters that threads over singletons, based on my earlier [`raggedMapThread`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9028/121); perhaps experimentation with it will demonstrate limitations or implementation difficulties that illuminate the reason for the existing design.

```
distMapThread[f_, expr_, level_Integer: 1, head_: List] := 
 Apply[f, 
   Map[Thread[#, head] &, 
     Flatten[expr, List /@ Range[2, level]],
   {level - 1}],
 {level}]
```

An example:

```
distMapThread[
  foo,
  {ReplacePart[Array[a, {3, 2, 3}], {{1, 2} -> x, {3, 2} -> z}], 
   ReplacePart[Array[b, {3, 2, 3}], {2, 1} -> y]},
  3
] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

A smaller example with a different head:

```
distMapThread[
 foo, 
 bar[Array[a, {3, 2}, 1, bar], ReplacePart[Array[b, {3, 2}, 1, bar], 2 -> x]],
 2,
 bar
]
```

> ```
> bar[
>  bar[foo[a[1, 1], b[1, 1]], foo[a[1, 2], b[1, 2]]], 
>  bar[foo[a[2, 1], x], foo[a[2, 2], x]],
>  bar[foo[a[3, 1], b[3, 1]], foo[a[3, 2], b[3, 2]]]
> ]
> ```

Comment: The example is very helpful!