# How to Thread with custom functions? Thread vs Map?

Tags: function-construction, core-language

This function finds n given the nth prime:

```
findPrime[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], i = 1; While[Prime[i] < n, i = i + 1]; i, False];
```

This works:

```
Map[findPrime, {7, 8, 37, 127}]

(* {4, False, 12, 31} *)
```

And this works:

```
Thread[PrimeQ[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]

(* {True, False, True, True}  *)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Thread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]

(* {1, False, 1, 1}  *)
```

Why doesn't that work?  Does `Thread` only work on built-in functions?

And why does `Thread` exist?  It seems to be redundant with `Map`.

Comment: That's interesting. The problem is, that `findPrime[{7,8,37,127}]` evaluates first, only then does `Thread` act. Also, the capabilities of `Thread`, though similar to `Map` at first glance, are different and in your example one of those differences just bit you in the arse :-) You should check the documentation of `MapThread`, if it's not immediately clear how different `Thread` is from `Map`.

Comment: BTW: do you know about `PrimePi[]`?

Comment: @J.M.  I sure didn't.  Thank you.  But hey, if I had known about PrimePi[], I wouldn't have learned what I learned today about Map[] and Thread[] and SetAttributes[].

Comment: This question is answered here: [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121),
[(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121),
[(84960)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84960/121).  I favor closing this question as a duplicate of all of these but I cannot do that alone.  Also related: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121),
[(33046)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33046/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I don't see that any of your linked questions addresses the first part of this question (pitfall of premature evaluation of argument of `Thread`). The second part (difference between `Thread` and `MapThread`) is certainly covered in those, though.

Comment: @Simon If the post about `Thread` and `MapThread` is understood it will also be understood why `Thread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]` "doesn't work" -- it is exactly the effect under discussion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see your point. I guess it seemed odd to me because the question itself isn't a duplicate, even if the answer is to be found in the answer to the other question. Also, that post seems to be pitched at a somewhat more advanced level than the question and answers here, so I don't know if someone with the question here would easily make the connection to the answer there. But you certainly know better than me what's appropriate to do with it.

Comment: @SimonRochester  Thank you for making that point, that a lot of us don't have the advanced understanding to make some connections like that.  Sometimes the experts are a little hard on us semi-noobs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One reason these "duplicate" questions get asked is because it's so hard to find those other questions. When it became clear to me that `Thread` wasn't doing what the help file says it does (as usual), I started searching here for the difference between `Thread` and `Map`. I got two results: one unrelated and this page.  Maybe I should be using Google to search SE instead, is that how you find them? I'm really frustrated and don't mean to be rude/mouthy, but let's assume we're not all over the site like you are. (I do appreciate all the help/input I've found from you on the site.)

Comment: @TravisBemrose  I always use Google, not the SE's Search.  If you put "Mathematica" followed by whatever you're looking for, most of the results you get will be Wolfram or SE anyway, and Google does a much, much better job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PrimeQ` is a `Listable` and `Map` will list `findPrime` over the list.

you can do this:

```
SetAttributes[findPrime, Listable]
```

and then:

```
Thread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]
```

or just directly:

```
findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]

(*{4, False, 12, 31}*)
```

If you want to keep `findPrime` free of any Attribute, you can do the following:

```
ClearAttributes[findPrime, Listable]


Activate@Thread[Inactive[findPrime][{7, 8, 37, 127}]]
```

or

```
Thread[Unevaluated@findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]

(*{4, False, 12, 31}*)
```

Comment: Oh!  I've never heard of SetAttributes[].  This is totally new to me.  THIS is exactly why I post these nit-picky questions, to get insights like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It's sad to see a question about `Thread` sidestep the discussion about `Thread` so I'll try to fill in the void, though it is becoming redundant after Simon's answer.

The normal sequence of evaluation for something like `f[a, b, c]` is to evaluate `a`, `b`, and `c` first (let's say, they are 5, 1, and 2, respectively). So then we get `f[5, 1, 2]`. And then Mathematica evaluates that if it has a rule set up for it. `Thread` is no exception.

As in the OP:

```
findPrime[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], i = 1; While[Prime[i] < n, i = i + 1]; i, False];
```

Therefore:

```
Thread[findPrime[{7,8,37,127}]]
```

evaluates to

```
Thread[
  If[PrimeQ[{7,8,37,127}], i = 1; While[Prime[i] < {7,8,37,127}, i = i + 1]; i, False];
]
```

wherein `PrimeQ[{7,8,37,127}]` evaluates to `{True,False,True,True}`, after which we have

```
Thread[
  If[{True,False,True,True}, i = 1; While[Prime[i] < {7,8,37,127}, i = i + 1]; i, False];
]
```

Finally we reach a point where Mathematica doesn't know what to do next, so it threads `If` over the first argument, while the other two arguments are the same for each case. Also, because `Prime[i] < {7,8,37,127}` cannot be evaluated as true or false, the `While` loop does not work any cycles. So after thread operates we get

```
{
  If[True, i = 1; i, False];,
  If[False, i = 1; i, False];,
  If[True, i = 1; i, False];,
  If[True, i = 1; i, False];,
}
```

That's why Simon suggested to restrict the input to `findPrime`. If `findPrime` were to accept only integers as arguments and not do anything if given other types of arguments, such as list,

```
Thread[findPrime[{7,8,37,127}]]
```

would have no chance of prematurely evaluating the argument of `Thread`, so the only thing to do would be to go right ahead and convert to

```
{findPrime[7], findPrime[8], findPrime[37], findPrime[127]}
```

To address the other question:

Also `Thread[f[{a,b,c},x,{d,e,f}]]` evaluates to `{f[a,x,d],f[b,x,e],f[c,x,f]}`, let's see you do *that* with `Map` or even `MapThread` :-)

Comment: Nice answer. It's like running `Trace` but with explanations!

Comment: @Simon, one would hope `TracePrint[]` could do things in a conversational manner… :D

Comment: New feature in Wolfram Alpha (coming soon, TM)?

Answer (score 7):

Another fix is to restrict the input argument.

```
Clear[findPrime]; 
findPrime[n_Integer] := If[PrimeQ[n], i = 1; While[Prime[i] < n, i = i + 1]; i, False];
```

That will keep `findPrime` from operating on the input until after `Thread` has had a chance to do its job:

```
Thread[findPrime[{7, 8, 37, 127}]]
(* {4, False, 12, 31} *)
```

Also, as mentioned in a comment by @LLlAMnYP, `Thread` is closer in capability to `MapThread` than to `Map`. Aside from the differences in functionality (`MapThread` has level specification, `Thread` has head and sequence specification, and automatic duplication of non-list arguments), the syntax of `Thread` can be very nice in situations like making lists of rules:

```
Thread[{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}]
(* {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3} *)
```

Comment: I don't see what that fixed.

Comment: Well isn't `Thread[findPrime[{7,8,37,127}]]` now returning the correct result?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP  I'm sorry, I should have said:  I don't understand why that fixed it.

Comment: @Jerry, as noted in the second paragraph, `findprime` here has been restricted to work only on integers, and will remain inert when applied to a list. At least, up until you put in `Thread[]`.

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as Simon's answer, we can also use `Unevaluated`.

```
Thread@Unevaluated@findPrime@{7, 8, 37, 127}
```