# Using Thread or MapThread over multi-level, ragged lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

This may be a rather strange question.  I will try to create a sort of minimal working example.

Suppose that I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`.  Both `list1` and `list2` are ragged, and they both have multiple levels.  However, `list1` and `list2` have the same number of elements, and their level distributions/arrangements are the same.  For example:

```
list1 = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f, g, h}, {i, j}}, {{AA, BB}, {CC, DD, EE}}};
list2 = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10}}, {{11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}}};
```

I would like to "thread" or "transpose" `list1` and `list2` to obtain `list3`, which has the same basic structure but with corresponding elements paired:

```
list3 = 
{{{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 4}, {e, 5}, {f, 6}, {g, 7}, {h, 8}}, {{i, 9}, {j, 10}}},
    {{{AA, 11}, {BB, 12}}, {{CC, 13}, {DD, 14}, {EE, 15}}}}
```

Is there a relatively simple way to obtain `list3` from `list1` and `list2`, apart from using a complicated nesting of `Table` commands?  `Transpose`, `Thread`, and `MapThread` all seem potentially useful, but not entirely straightforward for such "deep," ragged lists.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Duplicates: [(6102)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6102/121), [(9012)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9012/121), [(17400)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17400/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For this one, my memory has let me down - I was sure this wasn't asked before. Voting to close, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ClearAll[add];
SetAttributes[add, Listable];
add[x_, y_] := {x, y}
```

and now

```
add[list1, list2]
```

will give you what you want.