# List operations: how to combine two lists (pattern given)?

Tags: list-manipulation

Two lists (matrixes) are given:

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};
```

Expected return:

```
c = {{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}
```

Please, help to solve this. 
Useful references are also welcome.
**Added**:

> [duplicates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29155/using-thread-or-mapthread-over-multi-level-ragged-lists)

Comment: Have a look at `ArrayFlatten[]` or `MapThread[]` and `Transpose[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapThread can solve this.

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};
c = MapThread[List, #] & /@ MapThread[List, {a, b}]
```

The output is

```
{{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}
```

Comment: even shorter: `MapThread[List, {a, b}, 2]`

Comment: Even harder to read: `Transpose@{#1,#2}&@@@Transpose@{a,b}` :)

Comment: My fault not to think and search carefully before asking. Nice general [way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29155/using-thread-or-mapthread-over-multi-level-ragged-lists): `SetAttributes[add, Listable]; add[x_,y_]:={x,y}`

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};
c = {{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}

res = Thread[{a, b}] // Transpose[#, {1, 3, 2}] &

MatrixForm /@ {a, b, c, res}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};

Transpose /@ Transpose[{a, b}]
```

{{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}

Answer (score 2):

As of Version 13.1+, we could use `Threaded` like so:

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};

combine = Function[{e1, e2}, {e1, e2}, Listable];

a ~ combine ~ Threaded @ b

(* {{{x1,u1},{y1,v1}},{{x2,u2},{y2,v2}},{{x3,u3},{y3,v3}}} *)
```

But in this case it isn’t even needed as we are operating at the lowest level for two lists having the same dimensions:

```
a ~ combine ~ b
```

Comment: Of course, `combine[ a, Threaded[b] ]` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
Transpose[{a, b}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

> {{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[Variables,Partition[Flatten[a]*Flatten[b], 1]]
```

outputs

```
{{u1,x1}, {v1,y1}, {u2,x2}, {v2,y2}, {u3,x3}, {v3,y3}}
```

The Documentation Center is a great resource.

Comment: Thank U, I've noticed that DC has a direct solution to my 'problem'. BTW, output is not exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};
```

---

Using `Riffle`, `Partition` and `Thread`:

```
Thread /@ Partition[Riffle[a, b], 2]

(*{{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}*)
```

Or using `Table`, `Partition` and `Riffle`:

```
Table[Partition[Riffle[a[[i]], b[[i]]], {2}], {i, #}] &@ Max@Dimensions@{a, b}

(*{{{x1, u1}, {y1, v1}}, {{x2, u2}, {y2, v2}}, {{x3, u3}, {y3, v3}}}*)
```