# Is there any way to define pure functions with optional arguments?

Tags: function-construction, pure-function, optional-arguments

For example consider the following function:

```
Function[{u,v},u^2+v^4]
```

Is there anyway to define default values for the variables `u` and `v`?

I know that this is possible for ordinary functions as follows:

```
f[u_:1,v_:0]:=u^2+v^4
```

But I am looking for a way to do this with pure functions defined by `Function[]`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this with the named parameter form of `Function` but you can use [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) methods with `SlotSequence` (`##`):

```
f = {##} /. {u_: 1, v_: 0} :> body[u, v] &;

f[]
f[7]
f[7, 8]
```

> ```
> body[1, 0]
>
> body[7, 0]
>
> body[7, 8]
> ```

It is possible to give your pure function [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Attributes.html) using an [undocumented form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121).
For Hold attributes you could use `Hold` or `HoldComplete`:

```
g = Function[Null, Hold[##] /. _[u_: 1, v_: 0] :> HoldForm[{u, v}], HoldAll];

g[1 + 1]
```

> ```
> {1 + 1, 0}
> ```

Comment: I was thinking about the following construct: `Function[{u, v}, u^2 + v^4 /. {u -> 1, v -> 1}]` it is not the same as with optional arguments bacause one need to put coma: `f[,]`. Also, it seems to work well with Numeric arguments while for others ("a" for example), precedences are different.

Comment: But if well understood it can be very useful (in case of many agruments) because you can specify which argument you want to take it's optional value. For example `f[1,2,,2,,3]`, what is not so easy with standard *optional arguments*.

Comment: @Kuba Okay, why don't you post that as an answer?  It is an interesting interpretation of the problem.

Comment: Could you tell something about this `Null` issue you have faced lately?

Answer (score 7):

I have left bottom part of this answer as a warning against *not thinking* :)

Here is my improvement. It is not so handy but it allows us to specify which argument has to take it's optional value.

**edit -** scoping.

```
f = Module[{x, y, z},
    Function[{u, v, g}, x^2 y^4 + z^4 /. {x -> (u /. Null -> 3), 
                                          y -> (v /. Null -> 2), 
                                          z -> g}] (*3rd arg has no opt. value*)
          ]

f[2, 1, 1]
f[, , 1]
f[1, , 1]
```

> ```
> 5
>
> 145
>
> 17
> ```

I do not know if it is worth the effort but one may want to scope `x, y, z` and make replacement more compact.

---

### the warning :)

**The following method will work only when the result of the function has different value than the value of one of arguments. I such case the result is will be replaced by it's *optinal value*.**

Following examples are only **lucky coincidence**

This approach is not identical as *standard optional arguments* but it is interesting (*but not working :)* ).

```
f = Function[{u, v}, u^2 + v^4 /. {u -> 1, v -> 1}]

f[1,2]
```

> ```
> 17
> ```

```
f[,]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

As you see, it is not like with *standard optional arguments* because you have to put comma inside. Thats because

```
f = Function[{u,v} ...]
```

Comment: The precedence here isn't that strange according to the output of `f[,] // Trace`, this also explains why something like `f[a, 4]` fails: the main procedure here is `Null^2 + Null^4 /. {Null -> 1, Null -> 1}`.

Comment: @xzczd My first thouth was about this but then I checked f[1,4] and assumed that 4->1 will make an output `2`. This is not happening so I'm confused.

Comment: That's because `ReplaceAll` first evaluate the expression to be replaced before the replacement(`ReplaceAll` doesn't have `Attributes` like `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll`), so when the replacement begins, `1^2+4^4` has already evaluated to 257, so `4->1` won't work.

Comment: f[1, 2 a] gives the expected result, (1+16 a^4), but f[1, a] gives (2) which is not the expected result. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: @xzczd Ah, indeed, I was aware of this but then I've made tests with some mistakes and my interpretation was incorrect. Thank you :)

Comment: @M6299 That's because when the replacement really begins, the expression has become `256 + 4 a^2 /. {2 a -> 1, 4 -> 1}`, `4 a^2` doesn't match `2 a`, so it remains as it is :)

Comment: @xzczd I've manage to make it work with `ReplaceAll` :)

Comment: Nice update, but shouldn't you be localizing `x`, `y`, `z`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, but with such a long code I would stay with `f[u:2...` :) But I will think about this. I have to make replacement more compact, but I do not have time now to focus on this.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, I focus on the case of pure functions with one or more `Slot` in their body, which is different than the other answers.

First I present the function `optionalFu` which works just like `Function`, but which turns of a message. This message is the one that is generated when not all slots can be filled from the given input, like in `{#,#2}&[5]`. It is interesting to interpret this message as a warning, rather than an error and to ignore it, because *Mathematica* still fills all the slots it can. So `{#,#2}&[5]` evaluates to `{5,#2}` and it remains to be seen what to do with `#2`. The second function in this answer, `optFuWithDefaults`, replaces such slots (`#2`) with default values.

Be warned that the code  for `optionalFu` and `optFuWithDefaults` are both very unreadable, but they appear to work nicely and it definitely more informative to read the examples below than the code.

```
optionalFu =
 Function[Null,
  ReplacePart[
   Function @@ Hold[
     Null,
     Quiet[## &, {Function::slotn}],
     HoldAll
     ]
   ,
   {2, 1, 0} -> Function @@ Hold[##]
   ], HoldAll]

optFuWithDefaults = 
 Function[{functionBody, slotDefaultRules, nSlots},
  Module[
   {fuToken, argsHeld},
   argsHeld = Hold @@ Slot /@ Range[nSlots] /. slotDefaultRules;
   ReplaceAll[
    Function[Null,
     (Function @@ {
         Null,
         fuToken[##],
         HoldAll
         }) @@ argsHeld, HoldAll]
    ,
    Join[
     {fuToken -> optionalFu @@ Hold @@ Unevaluated@functionBody},
     OwnValues@argsHeld
     ]
    ]
   ], HoldAll]
```

There are three arguments in this last function: `{functionBody, slotDefaultRules, nSlots}`.

`functionBody` is really a list (or you can use any head) of arguments that you would normally pass to `Function`. So if we set `functionBody -> {{#, #2}}` then this corresponds to `{#, #2}&`, while `functionBody -> {Null, {#, Hold[#2]}, HoldAll}` corresponds to `Function[Null,{#, Hold[#2]}, HoldAll]`.

`slotDefaultRules` is a list of rules that sets default values for slots, if they are not present.

`nSlots` is the number of slots that are present in `functionBody`. I have chosen not to infer this from `functionBody`, because there may be functions inside `functionBody` and I don't want to mess with those. Instead, the user has to specify `nSlots`.

Simple example

```
fu1 = optFuWithDefaults[{{#, #2}}, {#2 -> 3}, 2];
fu1[1]
fu1[1, 2]
```

> ```
> {1,3}
> {1,2}
> ```

To quite some extent, functions in the `functionBody` argument are preserved.

```
fu2 = optFuWithDefaults[{{#,#2, {#,#2+5}&[#2,5]}}, {#2-> 3},2];
fu2[1]
fu2[1,2]
```

> ```
> {1,3,{3,10}}
> {1,2,{2,10}}
> ```

It also works with `HoldAll` and `RuleDelayed`

```
fu3 = optFuWithDefaults[
         {Null, {#, Hold[#2]}, HoldAll}, 
         {#2 :> Print[hello]}, 2];
fu3[1]
fu3[1, Print[goodbye]]
```

> ```
> {1,Hold[Print[hello]]}
> {1,Hold[Print[goodbye]]}
> ```

When using `Rule` and when not using `HoldAll`, arguments are also evaluated at appropriate times

```
fu4 = optFuWithDefaults[{{#, Hold[#2]}}, {#2 -> 2 + 2}, 2];
fu4[1]
fu4[1, 5 + 4]
```

> ```
> {1,Hold[4]}
> {1,Hold[9]}
> ```

As mentioned, you can use any head in the first argument (`functionBody`). This means you can also use `Function` and get a bit of syntax highlighting (but only in the first argument)

```
fu5 = optFuWithDefaults[
   {#, #2} &, {#2 -> 3}, 2];
fu5[1]
fu5[1, 2]
```