# Is it possible to separately call the default value of a variable which isn't at the end of the sequence?

Tags: pattern-matching, options, optional-arguments

After reading [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29206/is-there-any-way-to-define-pure-functions-with-optional-arguments#29207) I recalled an old question I once met. We know that we can set default values for variables of a function:

```
f[u_: 1, v_: 2, w_: 3] := u^2 + v^3 + w^4
```

We can use the default values like this:

```
f[]
```

> 90

like this:

```
f[u]
```

> 89 + u^2

and like this:

```
f[u, v]
```

> 81 + u^2 + v^3

However, what if I want to call the default value of a variable not at end separately? Something like

```
f[, v, w]
```

only gives

> Null^2 + v^3 + w^4

while what I want to see is

> 1 + v^3 + w^4

Of course it's easy to circumvent, but I still wonder if there's a more straight forward solution.

Comment: @Nasser Well isn't that what options are?

Comment: Just to clarify "value...not at end separately": The input `f[ , v, w]` is identical to `f[Null, v, w]`, so the value `Null` is being passed for `u`. The problem is how to program a certain behavior when a particular value, `Null`, is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Nasser Sure they could, but I don't think the solution would fit the OP's expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I added two more methods that should be easily extensible; I hope you like them. :-)

Comment: xzczd, I think you'll want to see the new answer I just posted.  My brain finally warmed up it seems. :^)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A simple solution

After writing a very long answer with one related method and four workarounds it suddenly hit me:
*We need the behavior of a Symbol with the [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html) attribute!*

Observe:

```
Attributes[foo] = {OneIdentity};

MatchQ[Null, foo[Null, i_: 1]]
```

> True

`Times` is such a function, therefore we may use:

```
f[(Null i_: 1) | i_, (Null j_: 2) | j_, (Null k_: 3) | k_] := {i, j, k}

f[, ,]
f[, "b",]
f["a", "b",]
f["a", , "c"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> {1, "b", 3}
> {"a", "b", 3}
> {"a", 2, "c"}
> ```

Success!

#### An edge case

Well, there is an edge case that must be addressed: when an argument is of the form `Times[Null, . . .]` and one actually wants that passed to the RHS:

```
f[Null * "x", "b", "c"]
```

> ```
> {"x", "b", "c"}  (* failure *)
> ```

This can be addressed by using a localized Symbol with the `OneIdentity` attribute:

```
ClearAll[f]

Module[{Star},
  Attributes[Star] = {OneIdentity};
  f[(Null⋆i_: 1) | i_, (Null⋆j_: 2) | j_, (Null⋆k_: 3) | k_] := {i, j, k}]
]

f[Null * "x", ,]
```

> ```
> {"x" Null, 2, 3}
> ```

### Meta-programming automation

Although I think this pattern is simple enough to use directly (at last!), we can also automate its creation if desired.  This function uses a very general replacement on any `Optional` pattern; more specificity may be desired such as targeting only the left-hand-side or looking no deeper than the first level; these are omitted for clarity but can be added if requested.

```
SetAttributes[makeFluidDefaults, HoldFirst]

makeFluidDefaults[x_Set | x_SetDelayed] :=
  Module[{oi},
    Attributes[oi] = {OneIdentity};
    Unevaluated[x] /. op_Optional :> oi[Null, op] | op
  ]
```

Now:

```
ClearAll[f]

makeFluidDefaults[
  f[i_: 1, j_: 2, k_: 3] := {i, j, k}
]

f[, ,]
f[, "b",]
f["a", "b",]
f["a", , "c"]
f[Null*"x", "b", "c"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> {1, "b", 3}
> {"a", "b", 3}
> {"a", 2, "c"}
> {"x" Null, "b", "c"}
> ```

Comment: Brilliant stuff, and quite interesting behavior on it's own. So what's happening is that `Replace[Null, foo[Null, i_: 1] :> i]` Matches the pattern, but still doesn't match the pattern, and therefore returns the default. This is kind of the behavior I would have expected from Alternatives, and I actually thought the difference in behavior was the inability of Mathematica to do this kind of simultaneous match/no match. Turns out that wasn't so.

Comment: Excellent!  After you left your comment, I tried to figure out something similar -- different approach, not nearly so elegant, and not yet bug free.

Comment: @jVincent I think the case with `Alternatives` is that each element is considered sequentially; as soon as `Null` in `Null | i_:1` matches the rest is ignored; this is possibly an important optimization even though it's a sad tradeoff in this context.  With this pattern `Null i_:1` it is a single expression; because of `OneIdentity`, `Null` is transparently converted to (or at least treated like) `Times[Null]` which then matches `Times[Null, i_:1]` with `i_:1` playing the usual role it would in any other expression.

Comment: @Michael out of curiosity: what was your avenue of attack?

Comment: It was to automate my "declarative method", with a somewhat different (and needlessly complicated?) idea than yours/jVincent's.  It was similar in that it was called in the same, but instead of `Optional`, I was going to use my own head `default`.  I'm not particularly good at this sort of thing, which is why I was trying to learn and maybe why I was tempted to complicate it.  I can post it if you like.  It works with basic patterns (I think), but I got stuck extending it to things like `PatternTest`.

Comment: @Michael I see.  What do you think of my automation of your method ("No.4")?  I haven't tested it extensively but I expect it to work.

Comment: "No. 4" works well.  I haven't tested it extensively.  But it doesn't allow for some arguments to have a default and others not.  Or does it?  This one above does, and very naturally, too. :)

Comment: @Michael For "No.4" you could simply use `Null` as the default for any parameters you don't wish to otherwise specify.  One could use `SparseArray` to generate a filled list from rules, e.g. `{3 -> "three", 7 - > "seven"}` but again how practical are *long* parameter lists anyway?  I'm glad you like this new one; I'm very pleased with it myself. :^)

Comment: I think if you use `Null` in "No 4", you get an infinite loop (up to `$IterationLimit`).

Comment: @Michael Indeed!  I didn't think that one through at all. <:-o  Won't work with No.3 either.  I could rewrite No.4 to fix to: simply never generate those definitions at all.  Do you think it's worth the bother given this answer?

Comment: No, I don't really think it's worth it.  But it's your call.

Comment: The second sample is now broken because of the issue mentioned here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224987/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

### Prioritizing patterns

If you *only* want the default values for the leading parameters (or some other order you choose), and not an arbitrary parameter at the time of the function call, you can prioritize the patterns as [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1690/121).

```
f[
  Shortest[u_: 1, 3],
  Shortest[v_: 2, 2],
  Shortest[w_: 3, 1]
 ] := u^2 + v^3 + w^4

f[v, w]
```

> ```
> 1 + v^3 + w^4
> ```

---

### Workaround No.1

I am still seeking a pattern-based solution to the arbitrary parameter problem, but until and unless I find it here is a work-around you may consider:

```
g[Null | u_, Null | v_, Null | w_] :=
 With[{uu = # &[u, 1], vv = # &[v, 2], ww = # &[w, 3]},
  {{"u", uu}, {"v", vv}, {"w", ww}}
 ]

g[, v, w]
g[u, , w]
g[u, v,]
```

> ```
> {{u,1}, {v,v}, {w,w}}
> {{u,u}, {v,2}, {w,w}}
> {{u,u}, {v,v}, {w,3}}
> ```

How this works:

- The pattern `Null | param_` is used for each parameter: if `Null` matches, `param` in the RHS is effectively replaced with `Sequence[]`.
- The function `# &` will return the first argument be there one or more than one; by specifying the optional/default values as the second paramter this will be returned iff the first is removed via `Sequence[]`.
- `With` may not always be necessary but it is used for robustness.

### Workaround No.2

I think this is a bit cleaner in principle than No.1 though neither is fully satisfying.

```
h[Null | aa_, Null | bb_, Null | cc_] :=
  {{aa}, {bb}, {cc}} /. {{a_: 1}, {b_: 2}, {c_: 3}} :> {a, b, c}

h[5, ,]
h[, 7,]
h[, , 13]
```

> ```
> {5, 2, 3}
> {1, 7, 3}
> {1, 2, 13}
> ```

### Workaround No.3

I don't think this is as clean as No.2 but it should be easier to extend.

For functions *without* a hold attribute you could use this:

```
ClearAll[f]

lhs : f[___, Null, ___] :=
  With[{def = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}},
    MapIndexed[# /. Null -> def[[First @ #2]] &, Unevaluated[lhs]]
  ]

f[1, , 3, 4, , 6, , , 9] // InputForm
```

> ```
> f[1, "2", 3, 4, "5", 6, "7", "8", 9]
> ```

The list `def` gives defaults by position for each parameter.  Here I chose numeric strings to make the positions evident while still illustrating the substitution.

If your function *does* have Hold attributes you will need a slightly more complicated replacement.  I will make use of `RuleCondition`<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121)</sup>:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]

lhs : f[___, Null, ___] :=
  Module[{i = 1, def = ToString ~Array~ 9},
    Replace[
      Unevaluated[lhs],
      {Null :> RuleCondition @ def[[i++]], x_ /; (i++; True) :> x},
      {1}
    ]
  ]

f[1, , 3, 2 + 2, , 6, , , 3^2] // InputForm
```

> ```
> f[1, "2", 3, 2 + 2, "5", 6, "7", "8", 3^2]
> ```

Notice that `4` and `9` have been replaced with `2 + 2` and `3^2` and that these correctly remain unevaluated after the substitution.

### Workaround No.4

[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) showed what is perhaps the most declarative method.  I don't think by itself it is as easily extensible, but then again there must be a limit to how many arguments a user is going to count anyway.  Nevertheless one could automate that method with meta-programming, so let's do it.

```
makeDefaults[fname_Symbol, defaults_List] :=
  fname @@@ {Pattern[#, _] & /@ #, #} & @ Table[Unique["$"], {Length @ defaults}] //
     Do[
        SetDelayed @@ ReplacePart[#, {{1, n} -> Null, {2, n} -> defaults[[n]]}],
        {n, Length @ defaults}
     ] &
```

Now:

```
makeDefaults[fn, {"one", "two", "three"}]

fn[u_, v_, w_] := u^2 + v^3 + w^4

?? fn
```

> ```
> Global`fn
>
> fn[Null, $2_, $3_] := fn["one", $2, $3]
>
> fn[$1_, Null, $3_] := fn[$1, "two", $3]
>
> fn[$1_, $2_, Null] := fn[$1, $2, "three"]
>
> fn[u_, v_, w_] := u^2 + v^3 + w^4
> ```

Comment: That's interesting :)  but what I expect is just a `f` which works for `f[, v, w]`, `f[u, , w]`, `f[ , , w]` and so on simultaneously…

Comment: @xzczd Alright.  That's a harder problem.  I cannot think of a way to do that with patterns alone.  Should I give my own work-around or since you said "it's easy to circumvent" is that not of interest?

Comment: Just add it, according to my experience, your work-around will probably show me something new :)

Comment: Oh, the pattern `Null|param_` is very interesting :D

Comment: I've always felt that this sort of thing should have been implemented by allowing `Optional` to take default values when not matched in `Alternatives`. It just seems like a more intuitive process, that whenever an optional isn't matched, it returns it's default. If that had been the case, this particular design pattern would be a trivial pattern match to `Null|v_:1`.

Comment: @jVincent That certainly would make this particular case easier! It might however complicate other uses?  I'm afraid `Alternatives` in this application doesn't get a lot of attention; I wouldn't be surprised if these things were never seriously considered before the implementation was chosen.

Comment: @jVincent I believe I have found a pattern that is not *too* far from that one; I have posted a second answer below.  Please take a look!  (It's still not as clean as what you propose.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to get the desired behavior, although it is not done with a single pattern:

```
Clear[f];
f[Null, v_, w_] := f[1, v, w];
f[u_, Null, w_] := f[u, 2, w];
f[u_, v_, Null] := f[u, v, 3];
f[u_, v_, w_] := u^2 + v^3 + w^4;

f[, v, w]
f[u, , w]
f[u, v,]
f[u, ,]
f[, v,]
f[, , w]
f[, ,]
```

> ```
> 1 + v^3 + w^4
> 8 + u^2 + w^4
> 81 + u^2 + v^3
> 89 + u^2
> 82 + v^3
> 9 + w^4
> 90
> ```

Comment: It's worth to mention that the order of the 4 definitions is important :)

Comment: @xzczd  The ordering of definitions is usually important, but I find it doesn't matter in this case if I randomly order them.  (The first three are specific and order makes no difference with them; the fourth is general, so *Mathematica* reorders it last no matter what.)  Is there an order you find does not work?

Comment: Ah… I should have checked it more carefully, you are right, the order doesn't care in this case.

Comment: This is a nice, declarative method that I should have included in the first place (you've got my vote).  I added an automated version of this as "No.4" to my answer; take a look if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is something in the direction of the named parameters as mentioned by Nasser, however a possible alternative could be:

```
gg[u[uu_:1],v[vv_:2],z[zz_:3]]:=Print[Column[{Row[{"u=", uu}],Row[{"v=", vv}],Row[{"z =",zz}]}]]

gg[u[1], v[2], z[3]]
u = 1 
v = 2 
z = 3

gg[u[], v[2], z[3]]
u = 1 
v = 2 
z = 3

gg[u[], v[5], z[]]
u = 1 
v = 5 
z = 3
```

Indeed, without naming the parameters or as alternative using Null (or any symbol like a placeholder), I guess there is no other way to say to the RHS of the definition, which variables is missing.

Comment: Forgive me, but this seems to be the worst of all worlds as it were.  You get neither the simplicity of using `Null` nor the flexibility of using Options.  If one is using named parameters I think in all cases it would be better to use Options directly, e.g. `gg["u" -> 1, "v" -> 2]`.