# i_:0|1 varies in v12.1: incompatible change or bug?

Tags: pattern-matching, notebooks, core-language, precedence

Just check

```
i_: 0 | 1 // FullForm
```

In *v12.0* or earlier the output is

```
Alternatives[Optional[Pattern[i, Blank[]], 0], 1]
```

[image]

But in *v12.1* the output becomes

```
Optional[Pattern[i, Blank[]], Alternatives[0, 1]]
```

[image]

Seems that the precedence between `:` and `|` varies in *v12.1*. Is this an intentional change, or a bug?

---

Some more observations. Behavior in *v3*:

[image]

Behavior in *v2.1*:

[image]

Comment: I suspect that this was a bugfix. Try running the same in command-line mode, or try `ToExpression["i_: 0 | 1 // FullForm"]`. It parses the same way as in 12.1.1. I expect this fixed an inconsistency between the FE's and the kernel's parser.

Comment: I wonder how you came across this example. I can't see a reasonable use for either `(i_ : 0) | 1` or `i_ : (0 | 1)`.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's a simplified example of course. I found this because it breaks my code here (see revision 6 ): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/132713/revisions . Your guess looks reasonable. Post it as an answer?

Comment: I think it's v3 that introduced the FE as we know it today. (So it makes sense.)

Comment: @sza Aha, here comes another broken example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29366/1871

Comment: With respect to `detoae` in your first comment, it's a cute use of `Times`, but, imho, the kind of cute that hides a bug: `(2 u)[t] /. detoae` — an extremely rare bug that is hardly likely to occur since `(2 u)[t]` is almost certainly a mistake, though you will find Q&A on site where users want to take a linear combination of functions and plug in `x` (there was one yesterday or the day before). I just bite the bullet and write [two rules](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cLIC5.png), one for derivatives and one for functions, because it's easier to understand.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah the two rules solution is more stable and pellucid. (I admit my pattern is kind of ostentation :) . )

Comment: I have to admit I like the way you can do such things in Mathematica.  But after a year or so of being pleased with myself, I tend to think a more straightforward way would be easier to deal with. :)

Comment: Actually the 2.1 screenshot answers a question for me.  Because when I saw the FE implementation, which dated back to the very beginning of the box parser, I couldn't figure out why it was done that way...in obvious contradiction to the docs.  But your 2.1 screenshot suggests that there was actually a change to the *kernel* (and maybe the docs as well) from 2.1 to 3.0.  Maybe the box parser, which was implemented in 3.0, was based on what would become out-of-date info from the kernel.  The box parser was implemented maybe a year before I started working on the FE.

Answer (score 9):

I expect that this was a bugfix that corrected an inconsistency between how the Front End and the kernel parse this code. Here's a comparison from M12.0.0:

```
In[1]:= $Version
Out[1]= 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

In[2]:= i_: 0|1//FullForm
Out[2]//FullForm= Alternatives[Optional[Pattern[i,Blank[]],0],1]

In[3]:= ToExpression["i_: 0 | 1 // FullForm"]
Out[3]//FullForm= Optional[Pattern[i,Blank[]],Alternatives[0,1]]
```

Comment: Seeing the behavior of _v2.1_ , I'm a bit confused which change should be regarded as bug... (Check my update. )

Comment: @xzczd I would always give the kernel's parsing priority because that is what is being used when a package (i.e. a plain text file) is loaded.

Comment: There's no need to guess here, or pick favorites between the kernel and the FE.  The documentation trumps everything.  Any variation from the documentation is always a bug (it might be a bug in the documentation, of course, but in practice that's pretty rare).
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html
And, yes, it was indeed an intentional bugfix.  Three external users had reported some variant of this, and IIRC it came up on the Redmine, too.

Comment: @JohnFultz So, the behavior of kernel is an incompatible change of kernel in v3.0, and the behavior of front end is a bug introduced in v3.0 and fixed in v12.1.0?

Answer (score 7):

I think V. 12.1.1 is correct, because the precedence of `Alternatives (|)` is larger than that of `Optional (:)`

```
Precedence /@ {Alternatives, Optional}
```

> ```
> {160., 140.}
> ```

This result of `Precedence` is obtainable both in V. 12.1.1 and V. 12.0.0 (no V. 12.0.1 at hand). So it looks like a bug in V. 12.0.x when interpreting shorthand symbols.

Comment: "it looks like a bug in V. 12.0.x" No, the behavior is much older than you thought. See my update.

Comment: @xzczd So what would `Precedence` return in those much older versions?

Comment: Same result in _v3_, but there doesn't seem to be a `Precedence` in _v2.1_.