# Correct slot assignment when mapping from different lists using pure function

Tags: map, pure-function

Given

```
expr = u == a1 + a2 x + a3 y;
```

and

```
uRep = {u1, u2, u3};
xyRep = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
```

I'd like to generate 3 equations

> ```
> {u1 == a1 + a2 x1 + a3 y1, 
>  u2 == a1 + a2 x2 + a3 y2, 
>  u3 == a1 + a2 x3 + a3 y3}
> ```

By replacing `u` with `u1,u2,u3` at a time, and at same time, replace `x` with `x1,x2,x3` and the same for `y`

Currently I do this using `MapThread` with explicit `Function` like this:

```
MapThread[Function[{z1, z2}, eq1 /. {u -> z1, x -> z2[[1]], y -> z2[[2]]}], {uRep, xyRep}]
```

But I was wondering what the syntax would be do it using pure function. I tried

```
MapThread[eq1 /. {u -> #1[[1]], x -> #2[[1]], y -> #2[[2]]} &, {uRepl, xyRepl}]
  eq1 /. {u -> #1[[1]], x -> #2[[1]], y -> #2[[2]]} & @@@ {uRepl, xyRepl}
```

and few others. They all produce errors due to wrong slot `#` mapping.

I am happy with the `Function` solution, but was wondering what the syntax will be using pure function. (I looked at many related questions, but could not find solution to apply for this case, I am sure I missed something)

Comment: Nasser, as a matter of personal curiosity may I know why you did not Accept my answer.  To *my* eye it is the nicest way, and I would like to know why you do not like it.  I ask this sincerely.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard all the answers were great and I +1 them all and would have accepted them all if I could. When all answers are good and I do not know which to accept, I normally accept the one which people have voted most to at the time. That is all. if there are two answers with same votes and both equally good, I flip a coin. Thanks again for your excellent answers as always.

Comment: You are welcome, as always.  Thanks for satisfying my curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MapThread[ expr /. {u -> #1, x -> #2[[1]], y -> #2[[2]]} &, {uRep, xyRep}]
```

works as expected. So do

```
(expr /. {u -> #1, x -> #2[[1]], y -> #2[[2]]}) & @@@  Transpose[{uRep, xyRep}]
```

and

```
(expr /. Thread[{u, x, y} -> ##]) & /@ (Flatten /@ Transpose[{uRep, xyRep}])
```

All three give

```
{u1 == a1 + a2 x1 + a3 y1, u2 == a1 + a2 x2 + a3 y2, u3 == a1 + a2 x3 + a3 y3}
```

Comment: ah! I was close. I was doing `#1[[1]]` all along for the first argument instead of just `#1`, since I also used `#2[[...]]` for the other argument! I did not notice `[[...]]` is not needed for the first one (now I know what the error meant :)

Comment: @Nasser, the error message should have given a hint :)

Comment: That is why I think the `Function` method was more clear. Arguments are defined using normal symbols, and in fixed location and position, so less chance of making a syntax error, and it looks more natural than using pure function with its `#` this and `#1` that. I am trying to learn to use `Function[...]` more now than pure functions, even though it takes few more keystrokes to write it.

Answer (score 3):

May this would be easier

```
list = MapThread[Prepend, {xyRep, uRep}];
#1 == a1 + a2 #2 + a3 #3 & @@@ list

(*
{u1 == a1 + a2 x1 + a3 y1, u2 == a1 + a2 x2 + a3 y2, 
 u3 == a1 + a2 x3 + a3 y3}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121):

```
MapThread[
  {##} /. {u_, {x_, y_}} -> expr &,
  {uRep, xyRep}
]
```

> ```
> {u1 == a1 + a2 x1 + a3 y1, u2 == a1 + a2 x2 + a3 y2, u3 == a1 + a2 x3 + a3 y3}
> ```

Note the express use of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) rather than the normal [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html), which allows `expr` to evaluate.

If `expr` will be input in the form given I feel this is the cleanest approach.

See also: [Is there any way to define pure functions with optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29206/121)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more ways;

```
uRep = {u1, u2, u3};
xyRep = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};

f = #1 == a1 + a2 #2 + a3 #3 &;

MapThread[f[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, {uRep, xyRep}]

MapThread[f, {uRep, Sequence @@ Transpose[xyRep]}]
```

Both of the `MapThread` expressions give

> ```
> {u1 == a1 + a2 x1 + a3 y1, u2 == a1 + a2 x2 + a3 y2, u3 == a1 + a2 x3 + a3 y3}
> ```