# Anonymous Function And Optional Arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

Is there a way to get an optional arguments to work in an anonymous function.

```
Function[{Optional@a},If[a,True,False]]
```

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29206/is-there-any-way-to-define-pure-functions-with-optional-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the [other Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29206) is much more likely to be found and the fact that my answer fits there quite nicely, I have [moved my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130152/4330) there.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work.

```
optionalFu =
 Function[Null,
  ReplacePart[
   Function @@ Hold[
     Null,
     Quiet[## &, {Function::slotn}],
     HoldAll
     ]
   ,
   {2, 1, 0} -> Function @@ Hold[##]
   ], HoldAll]
```

and an example

```
optionalFu[If[ToString@#1 == "#1", True, False]][1]
```