# Argument attributes for pure functions

Tags: functions, attributes

In his book, Leonid Shifrin says:

> One important limitation of the `#` - `&` notation for the pure functions is that it is not possible to assign attributes to them in this notation (unless some undocumented features are used).

What are these "undocumented features", and where are they (dare I say it) documented?