# Listable function behaving in an unexpected way

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, attributes

For example, if I define a function like this:

```
SetAttributes[func,Listable];
func@{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

it gives the result like:

> ```
> {{func[1], func[2]}, {func[3], func[4]}}
> ```

However, if I make a more specific define, like:

```
func = #*{1,1}&
```

then running the same code will create: `{{1,2},{3,4}}` instead of `{{{1,1},{2,2}},{{3,3},{4,4}}}`, like what it would normally do when you run `{{func[1], func[2]}, {func[3], func[4]}}`.

How come? What should I do if I want it to function as I wanted it to?

Comment: maybe use `func[x_] := x {1, 1};` in defining `func`?

Comment: `func = Function[x, x {1, 1}, Listable]` does also work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "what should I do if I want it to function as I wanted it to?"

see: [29169](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29169/5478)

```
func = Function[x, x*{1, 1}, Listable];
func @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}
> ```

And in case you don't need to keep a 'pure function' approach you can define `DownValues` as usual:

```
func // Attributes= {Listable};
funct[x_]:=x{1,1};
```

> "how come?"

`func` is `Listable` but by giving `OwnValues` to it `func=#*{1,1}&` you make that attribute irrelevant because of a standard evaluation steps.

See: [tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html)

The head is evaluated before attributes 'fire'. So

- `func@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`
- `#*{1, 1}& @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`

And there is no information about listability anymore.