# Why does `$Pre` need to be defined indirectly via some other function?

Tags: evaluation, system

The documentation for `$Pre` gives the following example

```
SetAttributes[saveinputs, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
saveinputs[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]}; new);
$Pre = saveinputs;
```

Evaluating the 3 input cells `a` then `b` then `Flatten[inputs]` gives

```
{a,b,Flatten[inputs]}
```

which is the the expected output. For some reason the intermediate step `$Pre = saveinputs` is necessary, but why? If one tries to define `$Pre` directly via

```
SetAttributes[$Pre, HoldAll];
inputs = {};
$Pre[new_] := (inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]}; new);
```

then $Pre does not work and `inputs = {}`. How is this different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can only guess. My guess is that it is only applied when it has `OwnValues` which your second example does not have.

p.s. you can do it in a one run:

```
inputs = {};
$Pre = Function[new, inputs = {inputs, HoldForm[new]}; new, HoldAll]
```

Comment: Thank you. I see now that the assignment `$Pre = saveinputs` is not being handled any differently from, say, `f = saveinputs`  (in terms of `OwnValues` and `DownValues` of `$Pre` and `f`).  It is also nice to see that it can be done with Function ...  difficult to use HoldAll with `&` :)

Comment: @AndrewNorton ... but possible :) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29168/pure-function-with-attributes-of-arbitrary-number-of-arguments-is-it-possible