# cascade application of Map or MapThread

Tags: map

In the following application

```
f = MapThread[If [#2 == 0, 0, #1/#2] &, {d, c}] // N;
```

I need to overlay another mapping operation so that `d` and `c` can be taken from two other lists of which `d` and `c` are just two corresponding sublists. I tried

```
F=Map[MapThread[If [#2 == 0, 0, #1/#2] &, {#3, #4}]&,{D,C}]
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this `g[d_,c_]:=MapThread[If[#2==0,0,#1/#2]&,{d,c}]; f=MapThread[g,{dd,cc}]` do what you want? That keeps one set of MapThread and #1,#2,& separated from the other.

Comment: How would I link d to dd where d is a sublist of dd, and similarly for cc and c?

Comment: The `f` MapThread is going to take two lists of lists. `f` will take one list from dd and one from cc. It will send those two lists to `g`. `g` will take one item from each of the two lists and calculate your result. Try `g[d_,c_]:=MapThread[If[#2==0,0,#1/#2]&,{d,c}]; f=MapThread[g,{{{m,n},{o,p}},{{q,r},{s,t}}}]` to see if the result is correct. If not then please provide an example input and what output should be. (D and C are functions defined by Mathematica and using those for variable names will cause problems) My method is only to put an inner Map or MapThread into a separate function.

Comment: If `d`s come from `D` and `c`s come from `C` shouldn't your `Map` be another `MapThread`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, shouldn't `F=MapThread[MapThread[If[#2==0,0,#/#2]&,{##}]&,{cc,dd}]` or `F=MapThread[MapThread[If[#2==0,0,#/#2]&]@*List,{cc,dd}]` do the trick?

Comment: Thanks to both Lukas and Bill a great deal. It appears that both will work. I implemented with Lukas' suggestion simply because the first option appears more intuitive to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If your sublists are all the same length you can use the third parameter of `MapThread`:

```
dd = {{d11, d12, d13}, {d21, d22, d23}};
cc = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23}};

MapThread[f, {dd, cc}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{f[d11, c11], f[d12, c12], f[d13, c13]}, {f[d21, c21], f[d22, c22], f[d23, c23]}}
> ```

If they are not you can use a second `MapThread`:

```
dd = {{d11, d12, d13}, {d21, d22}};
cc = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22}};

MapThread[MapThread[f, {#, #2}] &, {dd, cc}]
```

> ```
> {{f[d11, c11], f[d12, c12], f[d13, c13]}, {f[d21, c21], f[d22, c22]}}
> ```

Or my `raggedMapThread` from [MapThread over sublists of different length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9012/121)

```
raggedMapThread[f, {dd, cc}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{f[d11, c11], f[d12, c12], f[d13, c13]}, {f[d21, c21], f[d22, c22]}}
> ```

Or [kglr's `raggedThread`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221522/121) (reproduced here in full since it's short)

```
raggedThread = Inner[Thread@*#, ##2, List] &;

raggedThread[f, dd, cc]
```

> ```
> {{f[d11, c11], f[d12, c12], f[d13, c13]}, {f[d21, c21], f[d22, c22]}}
> ```